# C# Creating a class and GUI for an API questions

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

This is my first time building a GUI for an API, I’m building it as WPF C#. I have started a good portion of it but have a few questions. First off I created a ClassModelConnection(the fields I need to connect) How should I create a basic connection class that can be used in my other classes. Next should it be static? I’m not sure when I should create a static class or have it be normal. 
The API has methods and I need to use my GUI to get the parameters for the methods. Should I create a class(again static or normal) that does the methods I need from the API and I call this method I created from the button click and put in the variables needed here?
OR do I use the API method at the button click, im not sure what the proper way to do this is. I’m new with using APIs.. 
When should I use static classes, and interfaces
Here is the code in which what I mean:

```
    public static class Trading 
{
        private APIClient APIClient = new APIClient(true);

Stop orders has the parameters needed
        public static async void StopOrderBuy(StopOrders order)
        {

Api calls in here 
        }
    }
_________
```

---

Comment: Please do not tell us that you have done a good portion when you basically have done 5 minutes of work. You ask for the whole application structure. Too road, too opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static` is means global, and [global state is considered a bad thing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil). Global properties that never change (or never appear to change) is usually fine. So in this case, just create normal classes.

There is a general recommendation to [separate the UI from logic](https://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/separation.pdf). The reason is that the UI usually contains enough stuff just to manage the UI, so combining it with other logic usually reduces readability. It also makes reuse of logic code easier. So this would argue for wrapping the API-calls in another class.

But this somewhat depend on the use case. For a test application or similar it might be acceptable to just call the API directly from the button handlers.